# Using javascript to make an image work as font resizing button

Tags: javascript, html

Here is what I have now but the buttons still are not resizing the text. I have the value for each button set for 0.1 and -0.1 respectively, and the font size is currently set at 1em. Any ideas?

```
window.onload = startup;

function startup() {
    var fontButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("fontsizer");
    var i;
    alert(fontButtons.length);
    for (i = 0; i < fontButtons.length; i++) 
fontButtons[i].onclick = function(){resizeText(this)};
}

function resizeText() {
    var fontChange;
    fontChange = parseFloat(objButton.value);

    if (document.body.style.fontSize == "") {
        document.body.style.fontSize = "1.0em";
    }

    var currentFontSize;
    alert("changed");
    currentFontSize = parseFloat(document.body.style.fontSize);
    currentFontSize = currentFontSize+fontChange;
    document.body.style.fontSize = "currentFontSize+em"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call a function with parameters from `onclick`, put it inside an anonymous function so:

`fontButtons[i].onclick = resizeText(this);`

becomes:

`fontButtons[i].onclick = function(){resizeText(this)};`

Also, make sure you run `startup()` after the `.fontsizer` elements have been created. e.g. `window.onload = startup;` or something like this which you can run whenever:

```
document.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (document.readyState !== 'complete') 
      return;

    startup();  
}
```

working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ckn9sLfv/

Comment: Would I place window.onload = function(){startup();} at the top of the entire javascript sheet? Sorry I am very new to this

Comment: The buttons still aren't working is there a problem with my HTML?     


`<div id="fontbuttons">
                  <input type="image" class="fontsizer" id="fontdown"            value="-0.1" alt="-" src="fontdown.png" />
                  <input type="image" class="fontsizer" id="fontup" value="0.1" alt="+" src="fontup.png" />
               </div>`

Comment: Also I put `<body onload="startup()">` as my method to get it to load first in the html.

Comment: There were a couple of mistakes, e.g. `"currentFontSize+em"` should be `currentFontSize+"em"` and you need to pass the `objButton` to the function. So, `function resize()` becomes `function resizeText(objButton)` Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ckn9sLfv/ Btw, your `<body onload="startup()">` should work, but take out where I call `startup()` in the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
fontButtons[i].onclick = resizeText; // not (this);
```

You need to assign a *function*, not a return value (undefined).